# Sci-Fi movie playing in start and end of Seinfeld episode

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show, seinfeld

There is a episode of Seinfeld where he watches what appears to be a movie with a gentleman in a silver suit and dark sun glasses with his hands up in the air screaming into the sky about the end of the earth and that he was right.  Jerry thinks that it would be a good source of something in his comedy. The movie is then shown in the end of the episode.

To assist in identifying the episode, George thinks he's having a heart attack, and asks Jerry to take him to the hospital, to which he does.  Later on in the hospital, the doctor tells the group that he wasn't having a heart attack and he's fine.  The DR, however, did find that George re-grew a tonsil which must be removed.  George passes on the idea and goes to a homeopathic doctor, recommended by Kramer.  The session turns him purple, in turn results in him back in the hospital.

What I want to know: is the movie in the TV real, and if so, what is the name of the movie?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like [*The Heart Attack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Heart_Attack) and Wikipedia mentions..

> After watching a science-fiction B movie (featuring a cameo by **series co-creator** Larry David), ..

Which suggests the footage was made explicitly for the *Seinfeld* show.

The conclusion of the description adds:

> The hospital television shows the science fiction movie again, and Jerry remembers that what he wrote down, was a line from the movie (***Flaming Globes of Zigmund***). As he realizes this, he notes "that's not funny."

Comment: Cool.  you got the episode.  what I wanted to know is is the sci-fi movie real?

Comment: I thought it was pretty conclusive from the fact that the series co-creator played a cameo in it, but did it never occur to you to copy the title 'Flaming Globes of Zigmund' & put it into a search engine? The answer will be within the title of the top few hits!